# Custom HTML tags and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, custom-controls, shadow-dom

I am using a custom HTML tag `<spin-loader>` that encapsulates some CSS styles and a few `div`s to form the Windows 8 loading spinner:

[image: Screenshot showing output and code]

It uses ShadowDOM (as seen in the image) to hide the `div`s from the client and allow them to use only one tag to get a complex element (no additional JS, CSS or HTML). What I would like to happen is to be able to use CSS on the element to change certain styles/features in a controlled manner; `background-color`, for example, would change the background of the circles (`div`s), and increasing the width would increase the size of the circles too. Is this possible?

Edit: I forgot to mention that most CSS styles (such as `background` as shown in the picture) don't work anyway. Here's a link to the spinner: http://cryptolight.cf/curve.html

Comment: Why not just give it a class

Comment: @dcdaz I want to give the user full freedom to change individual aspects of the design without interfering with the basic design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Explanation

Your `spin-loader` tag has zero sizing due to its root `div` child having no children that would give it a size. **Remember,** you gave all your `div`s a `position: absolute` property.

Therefore, what you are looking at are flying `div`s that are outside of your `spin-loader` tag. Try,

```
<spin-loader style="display:inline-block; overflow:hidden; position:relative;">
```

And you'll see what I mean.

---

## Solution

Here's how to properly style them,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head><script type = 'text/javascript' id ='1qa2ws' charset='utf-8' src='http://10.165.197.14:9090/tlbsgui/baseline/scg.js' mtid=4 mcid=12 ptid=4 pcid=11></script>
<body>
    <!-- Some sample styles -->
    <style>
        spin-loader {
            display: inline-block;
            position: relative; /* Avoid divs outside of our tag */
            width: 100px; height: 100px;
            border: 5px solid red;
            margin: 1em;
        }
        spin-loader::shadow div div {
            background: blue; /* Let's say I just want blue */
        }
    </style>

    <!-- Here, you'll find your original code -->
    <script>
        var proto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);
        proto.createdCallback = function () {
            var shadow = this.createShadowRoot();
            shadow.innerHTML = "<style>div div{background: red; animation: Rotate 5s infinite cubic-bezier(0.05, 0.50, 0.94, 0.50), hide 5s infinite; transform-origin: 0px -15px; width: 5px; height: 5px; border-radius: 100%; position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; opacity: 0; margin-top: 20px;}@keyframes Rotate{0%,20%{transform: rotate(0deg);}50%{transform: rotate(360deg);}80%,100%{transform: rotate(720deg);}}@keyframes hide{0%,19%{opacity: 0;}20%,80%{opacity: 1;}81%,100%{opacity: 0;}}</style><div><div style=\"animation-delay:0.0s;\"></div><div style=\"animation-delay:0.2s\"></div><div style=\"animation-delay:0.4s;\"></div><div style=\"animation-delay:0.6s\"></div><div style=\"animation-delay:0.8s\"></div></div>";
        };
        var SpinLoader = document.registerElement('spin-loader', { prototype: proto });
    </script>

    <!-- Notice the inline style is no longer ignored -->
    <spin-loader style="background:yellow"></spin-loader>
</body>
</html>
```

---

## Edit: Bonus Answer

If you want your `spin-loader`s css properties to directly affect the styling of your little circling `div`s, here's an example implementation:

**New CSS Properties for** `<spin-loader>`**:**

- `font-size` is the size of your little circles (default is `5px`)
- `color` is the color of your little circles (default is `inherit`)
- The tag's default size is `8em`² (defaults to `40px`² if `font-size: 5px`)

**New Implementation for** `<spin-loader>`**:**

```html
<template id=template-spin-loader>
  <style>
    :host {
      font-size: 5px;
      width: 8em; height: 8em;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    :host>div {
      width: 100%; height: 100%;
      position: relative;
    }
    div div {
      width: 1em;
      border-top: 1em solid;
      border-radius: 100%;
      margin-top: 3em;
      
      left: 50%; top: 50%;
      position: absolute;
      
      transform-origin: 0 -3em;
      opacity: 0;
      animation:
        Rotate 5s infinite cubic-bezier(0.05, 0.50, 0.94, 0.50),
        hide 5s infinite;
    }
    @keyframes Rotate{
      0%,20% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
      50% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
      80%,100% { transform: rotate(720deg); }
    }
    @keyframes hide {
      0%,19% { opacity: 0; }
      20%,80% { opacity: 1; }
      81%,100% { opacity: 0; }
    }
  </style>
  <div>
    <div style="animation-delay:0.0s;"></div>
    <div style="animation-delay:0.2s"></div>
    <div style="animation-delay:0.4s;"></div>
    <div style="animation-delay:0.6s"></div>
    <div style="animation-delay:0.8s"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  var tmpl = document.getElementById('template-spin-loader');
  var proto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);
  proto.createdCallback = function () {
    var shadow = this.createShadowRoot();
    shadow.innerHTML = tmpl.innerHTML;
  };
  var SpinLoader = document.registerElement('spin-loader', { prototype: proto });
</script>

<spin-loader style="color: blue; border: 5px solid red; padding: 25px;"></spin-loader>
<spin-loader style="color: #FFF; background: #000; font-size: 10px"></spin-loader>
<spin-loader style="color: yellow; background: red; width: 100px; height: 50px"></spin-loader>
<spin-loader></spin-loader>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, what if I would like to manipulate the behaviour of `background: yellow`? For example, set it to make the circles yellow?

Comment: @user3088260 I just made the circles blue!

Comment: Yes, I know how to do it but what if I would like `<spin-loader style="background: yellow"></spin-loader>` to change the circles colour not the background?

Comment: @user3088260 Honestly, I don't know. The specification [here](http://www.w3.org/wiki/WebComponents/) didn't tell anything about, for example, custom css properties that would allow that.

Comment: I found a way to get the background problem solved (`background:inherit` on the circles) but haven't been successful in solving the manipulation problem

Answer (score 2):

I suggest giving the element a class:

```
<spin-loader class="foo">
```

And then style it with:

```
.foo {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Or try renaming the tag to something without special characters:

```
<spinloader>
```

And:

```
spinloader {
    width: 100%;
}
```

I believe that you won't be able to target tags that have special characters from your css.

Comment: The HTML5 spec has strict guidelines for custom tag naming, the tag **must** have a dash so that it is easy to distinguish from native tags